# How to invalidate timer after certain condition gets satisfied in the same method?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, nstimer

Hi i'm trying to show a custom progress bar in my iPhone app for that i'm writing a method to increment the progress bar value and once it's value becomes 100% then i need to invalidate my timer and i need to stop this recursion and show next viewController.
My code snippet is something like below,

```
-(void)progressNextValue
{
    progressValue += 1.0f;
    if(progressValue >= progress.maxValue){
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"end" message:@"TimeOut!!!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
        NSLog(@"Time Out!!!!");
        [mytimer invalidate];
        Second *sec = [[Second alloc] initWithNibName:@"Second" bundle:nil];
        [self.view addSubview:sec.view];    
    }

    progress.currentValue = progressValue;
    mytimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(progressNextValue) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    progress.maxValue = 100.0f;    
    [self progressNextValue];
}
```

Here even if my `progressValue = progress.maxValue`, `mytimer` is not getting invalidated.

Any help is appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting your timer each time the method is run regardless. Add a return statement, or place the timer instantiation in an else statement.

For example:

```
-(void)progressNextValue
{
    progressValue += 1.0f;
    if(progressValue >= progress.maxValue){
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"end" message:@"TimeOut!!!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
        NSLog(@"Time Out!!!!");
        [mytimer invalidate];
        Second *sec = [[Second alloc] initWithNibName:@"Second" bundle:nil];
        [self.view addSubview:sec.view];    
    } else {
        // Move this line inside the else statements so that it only gets run if 
        // the progress bar is not full.
        mytimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(progressNextValue) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }

    progress.currentValue = progressValue;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This code causes the issue,

```
mytimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(progressNextValue) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Here each time you are creating a **timer** with **repeat**, that's the issue.

Call the `progressNextValue` method from any other method:

```
-(void)tempMethod

    mytimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(progressNextValue) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

or just call it from:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    progress.maxValue = 100.0f;    
    mytimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(progressNextValue) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

Comment: Your first suggestion of changing just the `repeats` parameter will not fix the OP's problem.

Comment: Cool. Your answer is still slightly off. The issue isn't that he's creating a repeating timer, the issue is that he calls `invalidate` on the timer, but then always creates a new timer at the end of the method, creating a new timer and guaranteeing the method will be called yet again.

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer: he is calling the `invalidate` inside this condition `if(progressValue >= progress.maxValue)`. So this invalidate will be called after 10 iteration. For that 10 iterations, the methods, still creates new timers with repeat enabled.

Comment: 10 iteration means, if he set the maximum value to 10.

Comment: I see what you are saying. That is a minor issue. Probably best to fix it, even though I can't foresee it creating an issue.

Answer (score 0):

In order to invalidate your timer you need to call `[myTimer invalidate]`. Which you do. But `myTimer` in your case is not retained as far as I can see. So `retain` it when your alloc it and `release` it when you invalidate it.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Comment: Not necessary in case he is using ARC

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling your timer inside of `progressNextValue`, call it in `viewDidLoad` (or somewhere else that you want to start it). Keep a reference to your timer (so at the top of your page put `NSTimer *t`) and then when your conditions have been met do `[t invalidate]`;

The problem is that when you call your timer inside of 'progressNextValue' you're telling it to repeat, so invalidating the timer there doesn't do much (because you have multiple timers going).